# Cannot connect to any Compute Engine linux instance

Tags: ssh, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-sql

I tried to connect Cloud SQL proxy using the following command on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

```
./cloud_sql_proxy -instances=***.**.**.***=tcp:3306 -credential_file=/var/www/auth-keys/kinre-cloudsql.json 
using credential file for authentication; email=cloud-sequel-proxyauth@project.iam.gserviceaccount.com
Listening on 127.0.0.1:3306 for ***.****.***.**
Ready for new connections
```

After that, I lost SSH connection and Even if I try creating new instance and connecting, I'm unable to connect.

Error code is..`[/usr/bin/ssh] exited with return code [255]`

How to solve this problem?

Comment: How are you trying to ssh to the instance(e.g gcloud compute ssh INSTANCE-NAME, Cloud console)? You can check instance [serial console output logs](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/get-serial-port-output) to find useful debug information.

Comment: If you were able to solve this, you can post self-answer for other community members who may be seeing this same issue. If not, can you provide the information requested earlier to further troubleshoot.